# javax.el.ELException: listener="#{MyTab.tabChange2}": java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

MyTabs.xhtml

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Tab view</title>
    </h:head>

<h:form style="width:500px;" id="form">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

    <p:tabView dynamic="true">
         <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{MyTab.tabChange}" update="p1 p2 p3"/>
        <p:tab title="C" id="c">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" id="p1">
                <h:outputText value="#{MyTab.msg}"></h:outputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
         </p:tab>

          <p:tab title="C++" id="cpp">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" id="p2"> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{MyTab.msg}"></h:outputText>
             </h:panelGrid>
         </p:tab>
         <p:tab title="Java" id="java">
             <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" id="p3">
                <h:outputText value="#{MyTab.msg}"></h:outputText>
             </h:panelGrid>
             <p:tabView dynamic="false">
                <f:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{MyTab.tabChange2}" update="pg1,pg2"/>
                <p:tab title="JSP" id="jsp">
                    <h:panelGrid id="pg1">
                        <h:outputText value="#{MyTab.javaProg}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="JSF" id="jsf">
                    <h:panelGrid id="pg2">
                        <h:outputText value="#{MyTab.javaProg}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
             </p:tabView>
         </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>

</h:form>
</html>
```

MyTab.java

```
   package  mypak;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import org.primefaces.event.TabChangeEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="MyTab")
public class MyTab {

    private String msg="C";
    private String javaProg="j2ee";

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getJavaProg() {
        return javaProg;
    }

    public void tabChange(TabChangeEvent e){
        String id=e.getTab().getId();
        if(id.equals("c")){
            msg="C is a good programming language.";
        }else if(id.equals("cpp")){
            msg="C++ is better !";
        }else{
            msg="Java is the best :)";
        }
    }
    public void tabChange2(TabChangeEvent e){
        System.out.println("nested");
        String id=e.getTab().getId();
        if(id.equals("jsp")){
            javaProg="JSP is good option";
        }
        if(id.equals("jsf")){
            javaProg="JSF is the better";
        }
    }
}
```

Error I am getting when I click on a nested tab

```
Sep 16, 2015 9:45:37 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: /MyTabs.xhtml @31,81 listener="#{MyTab.tabChange2}": java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: /MyTabs.xhtml @31,81 listener="#{MyTab.tabChange2}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:462)
    at org.primefaces.event.TabChangeEvent.processListener(TabChangeEvent.java:42)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:809)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.broadcast(UITabPanel.java:1259)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mypak.MyTab.tabChange2(MyTab.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 32 more
```

I am using JSF 2,Prime Faces 5.2 ,Tomcat 8.
How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You have `<f:ajax event="tabChange" >` instead of `<p:ajax event="tabChange" >`

Comment: Thank you Geinmachi . It worked . It was a silly mistake :)

Comment: @Geinmachi, please reformulate as an answer so that you can get the credit for providing the right answer.